# Javascript & Nested JSON issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I'm trying to put together some JSON and parse it out into jquery but I am doing something wrong with my JSON syntax.  I tried running it through a validator but it doesn't really tell me what I'm doing wrong.  Can somebody point out the error of my ways?

```
var searchresults = [
{
    "providerlisting": [
    {
        "nametitle": "Cory M Spears, MD, FACP",
        "caretype": "Internal Medicine",
        "preferredProvider": true,
        "address1": "289 N. Highland Ave.",
        "address2": "",
        "cityStateZip": "Atlanta, GA 30306",
        "coverage": "/images/example.png",
        "status": "Out of Network",
        "psn": "",
        "dcontact": "urlhere",
        "save": "urlhere",
        "rating": "urlhere",
    },
    {
        "nametitle": "Jimmy Dean, MD, FACP",
        "caretype": "External Medicine",
        "preferredProvider": false,
        "address1": "3 Piedmont Rd.",
        "address2": "",
        "cityStateZip": "Atlanta, GA 30706",
        "coverage": "/images/example2.png",
        "status": "In Network",
        "psn": "urlhere",
        "dcontact": "urlhere",
        "save": "urlhere",
        "rating": "urlhere",
    },
    {
        "nametitle": "John Doe, DD, PM",
        "caretype": "Internal Medicine",
        "preferredProvider": true,
        "address1": "500 Ponce De Leon Ave",
        "address2": "Suite 5",
        "cityStateZip": "Atlanta, GA 30706",
        "coverage": "/images/example2.png",
        "status": "Out of Network",
        "psn": "urlhere",
        "dcontact": "urlhere",
        "save": "urlhere",
        "rating": "urlhere",
    }]
},
{
"categories": [{
    "categoryMenu": [
        {
            "providertype": [
                {
                    "title": "Doctor",
                    "link": "#doctor",
                    "amount": "400"
                },
                 {
                     "title": "Hospital",
                     "link": "#hospital",
                     "amount": "40"
                 },
                 {
                     "title": "Urgent Care",
                     "link": "#urgentCare",
                     "amount": "37"
                 }
            ]
        },
        {
            "specialty": [
                {
                    "title": "Allergy and Immunology",
                    "link": "#allergyAndImmunology",
                    "amount": "2"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Audiology",
                    "link": "#audiology",
                    "amount": "3"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Allergy and Immunology",
                    "link": "#allergyAndImmunology",
                    "amount": "6"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Ambulatory Surgical Center",
                    "link": "#ambulatorySurgicalCenter",
                    "amount": "4"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                {
                    "title": "Male",
                    "link": "#male",
                    "amount": "67"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Female",
                    "link": "#female",
                    "amount": "3"
                }
            ]
        }
    }]
}];
```

Comment: [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.org) clearly reports an error on line 16. There's a stray comma. That's an error in real JSON, but that's not what you posted; you posted a JavaScript statement, and it wouldn't be an error in JavaScript (except in older IE versions).

Comment: What you currently have is a script that assigns a huge object literal to a variable. If you want [JSON](http://json.org/) (what the validator validates), you would need to take only the literal without its surroundings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `,` at the end of each

```
 "rating": "urlhere"
```

there was a `]` missing on the third last line, below is a valid json object

```
var searchresults = [{
    "providerlisting": [{
        "nametitle": "Cory M Spears, MD, FACP",
            "caretype": "Internal Medicine",
            "preferredProvider": true,
            "address1": "289 N. Highland Ave.",
            "address2": "",
            "cityStateZip": "Atlanta, GA 30306",
            "coverage": "/images/example.png",
            "status": "Out of Network",
            "psn": "",
            "dcontact": "urlhere",
            "save": "urlhere",
            "rating": "urlhere"
    }, {
        "nametitle": "Jimmy Dean, MD, FACP",
            "caretype": "External Medicine",
            "preferredProvider": false,
            "address1": "3 Piedmont Rd.",
            "address2": "",
            "cityStateZip": "Atlanta, GA 30706",
            "coverage": "/images/example2.png",
            "status": "In Network",
            "psn": "urlhere",
            "dcontact": "urlhere",
            "save": "urlhere",
            "rating": "urlhere"
    }, {
        "nametitle": "John Doe, DD, PM",
            "caretype": "Internal Medicine",
            "preferredProvider": true,
            "address1": "500 Ponce De Leon Ave",
            "address2": "Suite 5",
            "cityStateZip": "Atlanta, GA 30706",
            "coverage": "/images/example2.png",
            "status": "Out of Network",
            "psn": "urlhere",
            "dcontact": "urlhere",
            "save": "urlhere",
            "rating": "urlhere"
    }]
}, {
    "categories": [{
        "categoryMenu": [{
            "providertype": [{
                "title": "Doctor",
                    "link": "#doctor",
                    "amount": "400"
            }, {
                "title": "Hospital",
                    "link": "#hospital",
                    "amount": "40"
            }, {
                "title": "Urgent Care",
                    "link": "#urgentCare",
                    "amount": "37"
            }]
        }, {
            "specialty": [{
                "title": "Allergy and Immunology",
                    "link": "#allergyAndImmunology",
                    "amount": "2"
            }, {
                "title": "Audiology",
                    "link": "#audiology",
                    "amount": "3"
            }, {
                "title": "Allergy and Immunology",
                    "link": "#allergyAndImmunology",
                    "amount": "6"
            }, {
                "title": "Ambulatory Surgical Center",
                    "link": "#ambulatorySurgicalCenter",
                    "amount": "4"
            }]
        }, {
            "gender": [{
                "title": "Male",
                    "link": "#male",
                    "amount": "67"
            }, {
                "title": "Female",
                    "link": "#female",
                    "amount": "3"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}];
```

Comment: When I threw it into Notepad++ and formatted it with JSMin, it also looks like he's missing a closing square bracket `]` at the end

Comment: @valverij yes indeed, added the full working copy as it would be hard to point out which line, etc

Comment: Thanks, it still isn't running through jsonlint.com though.  I'm guessing it doesn't like the javascript.  Where should I copy out and end copy in order to get it to run correctly through the validator?

Comment: @Chad it passes on JSONLint, that is a json object validator, not javascript validator, to test it there, you would need to remove the variable declaration/assignment and the `;` at the end

Comment: so start with { "providerlisting": [{... ?

Comment: @Chad basically everything after the `=` to just before the ';'

Answer (score 0):

There are only `,` commas after a key/value pairs in objects if there is another one following it. (Same goes for Arrays as well)

For example:

```
var a = {
   key  : 'value',
   keyB : 'value'   // <-- there is no trailing comma before an object ends
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know http://jsonlint.com/?

You have to realise, an object in javascript is nearly the same like an associative array.

I think you should read a bit more about Objects and Arrays in Javascript.

Try this:

```
var searchresults = {
        "providerlisting": [
            {
                "nametitle": "Cory M Spears, MD, FACP",
                "caretype": "Internaenter code herel Medicine",
                "preferredProvider": true,
                "address1": "289 N. Highland Ave.",
                "address2": "",
                "cityStateZip": "Atlanta, GA 30306",
                "coverage": "/images/example.png",
                "status": "Out of Network",
                "psn": "",
                "dcontact": "urlhere",
                "save": "urlhere",
                "rating": "urlhere"
            },
            {
                "nametitle": "Jimmy Dean, MD, FACP",
                "caretype": "External Medicine",
                "preferredProvider": false,
                "address1": "3 Piedmont Rd.",
                "address2": "",
                "cityStateZip": "Atlanta, GA 30706",
                "coverage": "/images/example2.png",
                "status": "In Network",
                "psn": "urlhere",
                "dcontact": "urlhere",
                "save": "urlhere",
                "rating": "urlhere"
            },
            {
                "nametitle": "John Doe, DD, PM",
                "caretype": "Internal Medicine",
                "preferredProvider": true,
                "address1": "500 Ponce De Leon Ave",
                "address2": "Suite 5",
                "cityStateZip": "Atlanta, GA 30706",
                "coverage": "/images/example2.png",
                "status": "Out of Network",
                "psn": "urlhere",
                "dcontact": "urlhere",
                "save": "urlhere",
                "rating": "urlhere"
            }
        ],
        "categories": {
            "categoryMenu": {
                "providertype": [
                    {
                        "title": "Doctor",
                        "link": "#doctor",
                        "amount": "400"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Hospital",
                        "link": "#hospital",
                        "amount": "40"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Urgent Care",
                        "link": "#urgentCare",
                        "amount": "37"
                    }
                ],
                "specialty": [
                    {
                        "title": "Allergy and Immunology",
                        "link": "#allergyAndImmunology",
                        "amount": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Audiology",
                        "link": "#audiology",
                        "amount": "3"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Allergy and Immunology",
                        "link": "#allergyAndImmunology",
                        "amount": "6"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Ambulatory Surgical Center",
                        "link": "#ambulatorySurgicalCenter",
                        "amount": "4"
                    }
                ],
                "gender": [
                    {
                        "title": "Male",
                        "link": "#male",
                        "amount": "67"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Female",
                        "link": "#female",
                        "amount": "3"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please find the corrected Json string

var searchresults = [
{
    "providerlisting": [
    {
        "nametitle": "Cory M Spears, MD, FACP",
        "caretype": "Internal Medicine",
        "preferredProvider": true,
        "address1": "289 N. Highland Ave.",
        "address2": "",
        "cityStateZip": "Atlanta, GA 30306",
        "coverage": "/images/example.png",
        "status": "Out of Network",
        "psn": "",
        "dcontact": "urlhere",
        "save": "urlhere",
        "rating": "urlhere",
    },
    {
        "nametitle": "Jimmy Dean, MD, FACP",
        "caretype": "External Medicine",
        "preferredProvider": false,
        "address1": "3 Piedmont Rd.",
        "address2": "",
        "cityStateZip": "Atlanta, GA 30706",
        "coverage": "/images/example2.png",
        "status": "In Network",
        "psn": "urlhere",
        "dcontact": "urlhere",
        "save": "urlhere",
        "rating": "urlhere",
    },
    {
        "nametitle": "John Doe, DD, PM",
        "caretype": "Internal Medicine",
        "preferredProvider": true,
        "address1": "500 Ponce De Leon Ave",
        "address2": "Suite 5",
        "cityStateZip": "Atlanta, GA 30706",
        "coverage": "/images/example2.png",
        "status": "Out of Network",
        "psn": "urlhere",
        "dcontact": "urlhere",
        "save": "urlhere",
        "rating": "urlhere",
    }]
},
{
"categories": [{
    "categoryMenu": [
        {
            "providertype": [
                {
                    "title": "Doctor",
                    "link": "#doctor",
                    "amount": "400"
                },
                 {
                     "title": "Hospital",
                     "link": "#hospital",
                     "amount": "40"
                 },
                 {
                     "title": "Urgent Care",
                     "link": "#urgentCare",
                     "amount": "37"
                 }
            ]
        },
        {
            "specialty": [
                {
                    "title": "Allergy and Immunology",
                    "link": "#allergyAndImmunology",
                    "amount": "2"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Audiology",
                    "link": "#audiology",
                    "amount": "3"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Allergy and Immunology",
                    "link": "#allergyAndImmunology",
                    "amount": "6"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Ambulatory Surgical Center",
                    "link": "#ambulatorySurgicalCenter",
                    "amount": "4"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                {
                    "title": "Male",
                    "link": "#male",
                    "amount": "67"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Female",
                    "link": "#female",
                    "amount": "3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
}];

alert(JSON.stringify(searchresults))
```